# Why is _Generic keyword supported in c99 or c90 modes?

Tags: c, c99, c11, c89, ansi-c

I wrote a simple C program to test the availability of **_Generic** keyword.

```
int main() {
    int _Generic;
}
```

I ran the program with *gcc-5.3.1* and *clang-3.8.0* compilers on Ubuntu.

Obviously this program generated an error when compiled in the latest c11 standard.

But, when compiled with **-std=c90** and **-std=c99** flags, it generated an error as well. Whereas, the _Generic keyword was only introduced in c11 standard.

Is it that the -std= flags behave differently? And is there a way to test the pure c90 and c99 standards?

*EDIT:*

I did run the same program with other identifiers which are not keywords as per c11 standard. Like:

```
int _Hello;
int _Gener;
```

And they compiled successfully without any errors or warnings.
This is probably because of 7.1.3, which says

> If the program declares or defines an identifier in a
>   context in which it is reserved (other than as allowed by 7.1.4), or defines a reserved
>   identifier as a macro name, the behavior is undefined

as said by @Art and @Lundin.

Comment: isn't it like anything starting with underscore is "reserved"? or am I being too aggressive? edit: It's `__` or `_<uppercase>`, to be precise.

Comment: ANSI C: "All other identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an
upper-case letter or another underscore are reserved.  If the program
defines an external identifier with the same name as a reserved
external identifier, even in a semantically equivalent form, the
behavior is undefined.". So the compiler is technically correct.

Comment: @Art: Note that "the behavior of X is undefined" isn't intended to mean "programs that seek merely to be conforming, rather than strictly conforming, are forbidden from doing x", but rather that the Standard is *agnostic* as to whether implementations should process X usefully.  I think the intention here is to give implementations a family of identifiers to which they may attach any behavior they would regard as useful--not to suggest that implementations do anything wacky with any identifiers to which they haven't attached useful meanings.  Among other things...

Comment: ...implementations which by convention define reserved-name macros for each new identifier (e.g. treating `__WOOZLE` as a predefined macro for the new intrinsic `___WOOZLE`) could add features and allow code to use them while maintaining compatibility with older code via e.g. `#ifndef __UNSPEC_CHOICE(x,y)` `#define __UNSPEC_CHOICE(x,y) x` `#endif`.  If a new compiler will interpret that as an intrinsic that expands to x or y, whichever is more efficient, code which is written to exploit that, but starts with the above `#ifdef`, could work on old or new compilers.

Answer (score 8):

Because you are not allowed to use identifiers that start with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter. 7.1.3:

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase
>   letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

This rule has been there since C90 and is nothing new.

---

A more reliable way to test for standard version would be to use the standard macros defined for that very purpose:

```
#ifndef __STDC__
  #error Not a standard C compiler.
#endif

#ifdef __STD_VERSION__
  #if (__STDC_VERSION__ == 199409L)
    /* C95 */
  #elif (__STDC_VERSION__ == 199901L)
    /* C99 */
  #elif (__STDC_VERSION__ == 201112L)
    /* C11 */
  #else
    /* Cxx, unknown future standard */
  #endif
#else /* __STDC__ defined but not __STD_VERSION__ */
  /* C90 */
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the reference. But, I ran the same program with other identifiers like _Hello, _Gene etc. and it compiled without any problem. Probably it is the case that behaviour is undefined as written in 7.1.3 and which was pointed out by @Art.

Comment: @AseemSharan, exactly it is undefined, meaning what it says, not defined. So the compiler may do what pleases with your code. In view of the C11, they do already something with `_Generic` and not with the other identifiers that you tried.